# Read line and combine duplicate entries based on one of the fields

Tags: java

The following Java code reads lines from an input text file and will output the entry that has the highest number in field-2 to an output file:

**INPUT:**

> William J. Clinton 6 Q1124 
>   42nd President of the United States 6 Q1124 
>   Bill Clinton,6,Q1124 
>   Bill Clinton,14,Q9890 
>   Bill Clinton,5,Q9880 
>   William Jefferson Clinton,6,Q1124

**OUTPUT:**

> William J. Clinton,Q1124 
>  42nd President of the United
>   States,Q1124 
>  Bill Clinton,Q9890 (this Q-ID selected because
>   field-2 was highest number "14") 
>   William Jefferson Clinton,Q1124

Could you offer suggestions on making this more elegant?

```
/*
 * This class uses a method to combine duplicate Wiki keys into one and
 * selecting the Qid of the one with largest link count
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length < 2) {
        usage();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //
    try {
        // Create output file
        BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(args[1]),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // read input file
        BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[0]),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String key = "";
        int links = 0;
        String qID = "";

        String next, line = br.readLine();
        for (boolean first = true, last = (line == null); !last; first = false, line = next) {
            last = ((next = br.readLine()) == null);

            String[] entry = line.split(",");

            if (first) {
                // only assign current values
                key = entry[0];
                links = new Integer(entry[1]);
                qID = entry[2];

            } else if (last) {

                //check if key is a duplicate
                if(key.equals(entry[0])){
                    //use the Qid from the highest links
                    int temp = new Integer(entry[1]);
                    if(links < temp){
                        //write entry to output higher links
                        out.write(key + "," + entry[2] + "\n");
                    }else{
                        //write entry to output using current
                        out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");
                    }


                }else{
                    //write last entry to output
                    out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");
                    out.write(entry[0] + "," + entry[2] + "\n");
                }

            } else {

                //check if key is a duplicate
                if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(entry[0])){
                    //use the Qid from the highest links
                    int temp = new Integer(entry[1]);
                    if(links < temp){
                        links = temp;
                        qID = entry[2];
                    }


                }else{
                    //write entry to output
                    out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");

                    //reassign current values
                    key = entry[0];
                    links = new Integer(entry[1]);
                    qID = entry[2];
                }

            }   

        }

        // Close the output stream
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

private static void usage() {
    System.err.println("Usage: CombineKeys InputFile OutputFile");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm far from a Java expert, but a few things jumped out at me

---

You forgot to close the reader (`br`).

---

Do not close the streams inside of the try. What happens if an exception gets thrown before the close commands are reached? You need a `finally` block. Or, better yet, if you're using Java 7 or above, use a try-with-resources block.

---

If you're only error handling is to just print out the message, I'd be tempted to go ahead and let the exception bubble up and kill the program. Unless you're just trying to go for a more simple error, in which case hiding the stack trace could be nice.

---

I would just let `key` be `null` the first time around and check for that instead of using `first`.

---

I might try to restructure the `for` conditions. They're very confusing in the current form. Perhaps loop as long as you successfully read a line, and then handle the `last` logic outside of the `for` loop. That way you don't have to have so much going on inside of the loop.

---

On a minor note, you should try to create the reader before the writer. That way you don't create an output file if you can't open the input one.

---

The repetition in the `last` and `else` blocks should be refactored out into a common case. Based on that they do the exact same thing, I'm not actually sure why `last` get's special treatment.

---

I would use `Integer.parseInt` instead of using unboxing on `new Integer(str)`.

---

`temp` is a bad variable name. Name it something descriptive of what it actually is.

---

Don't bother commenting really obvious things ("Catch exception if any" for example).

---

Sometimes you use spaces like `if (...)` and sometimes you don't. Pick one and stick with it (by which I really mean always use spaces :p).

---

All in all, my Java is a bit rusty, so take this with a grain of salt, but, I would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: CombineKeys InputFile OutputFile");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        out = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(args[1]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[0]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String key = null;
        int links = 0;
        String qID = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] entry = line.split(",");

            if (entry[0].equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                int tmpLinks = Integer.parseInt(entry[1]);
                if (links < tmpLinks){
                    links = tmpLinks;
                    qID = entry[2];
                }
            } else {
                if (key != null) {
                    out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");
                }
                key = entry[0];
                links = Integer.parseInt(entry[1]);
                qID = entry[2];
            }
        }
        if (key != null) {
            out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really like the repetition of the outputting, but I can't figure out a way around that. Also, due to the nesting level, I would probably pull the actual processing into a new method that takes in the two already opened streams.